# Netbeans: how do I change the name of a project?

Tags: java, netbeans

I need to change the name of my application, so people who download and install it can see the name but I don't know where to do it.

What file do I need to edit?

Answer (score 36):

you must right click on your project in Project window [ctrl + 1] and choose rename option for

renaming your project name.

Comment: i Did this but in my mobile its still the old name

Comment: folder name was renamed. but the project name still the same.

Comment: This doesn't change the File name. Strange.

Answer (score 4):

if your project is mobile Project you must right click on project name , select properties options and then on Application Descriptor edit MIDlet-name value.

[image: Application Descriptor ScreenShot]

Answer (score 3):

If you use gradle:
BuildScripts/Project/settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'yourprojectname'
```

Answer (score 2):

If your project is Maven based, you can either add/update the application name in pom.xml (found in Project Files folder) or go to File >> Project Properties and add/update the application name.

Comment: what do you see in the dialog box when you open File >> Project Properties?

Answer (score 2):

Open "project.xml" file under nbproject folder inside the project folder of the one you want to change the name.
it is in the tag `<name>`.

Just change it and that is it.

Answer (score 0):

open project.properties in dir nbproject
look up to manifest.midlets and change the name after MIDlet

Answer (score 0):

Rightclick on the project node and select rename.
If you want the folder of the project also to have the new name or whatever that wasnt renamd then :
1.*in build.xml in text editor find old name and replace with new one. Its place is: C:\NBProjectsFolder\OldName\build.xml  Save that.*
2. *Remove all cash situated in , e.g.: C:\NBProjectsFolder\OldName\build\gwt-unitCache.*
 *3. Find in C:\NBProjectsFolder\OldName\nbproject\private private.xml file and edit it in a text redactor by renaming old name within the file. Save that.*

Do all the changes   when the Netbeans was closed.
After opening the Ntbeans it may ask to reimport the project and all files you changed will be recognized/recreated automatically

Answer (score 0):

This is for Netbeans 14.

From experience, there are 3 things you need to do:

1. In project window, right-click on project then select "Rename".
2. Right-click on package then select "Refactor" -> "Rename".
3. Right-click on main class then select "Refactor" -> "Rename".

For 1: apply changes to "Change Display Name", "Change ArtifactID", "Rename Folder".

- Also, be careful not to do stuff that prevents renaming of folder. For example, don't have folder open in Windows Explorer to be safe.

For 2 and 3: tick "Apply Rename on Comments" as well if you want comments to be renamed.

Also, some loose ends that may need to be tied up:

1. Inside pom.xml file: rename projects/groupID value.
2. And rename project/properties/exec.mainClass value.