# Netbeans Java application - change title or name of application

Tags: java, netbeans

When I run my app (in Netbeans) the title of the app (in the top left corner of my OS) is the name of the java class (not the name I want or the name of the project).

If there a way to change this so it is more meaningful? I am sure there should be but I can't seem to find out how..

I can change the title of the window that opens but I want the name in the top left corner to be different (i.e. the programs name).

Hope this is clear?

Thanks

EDIT WITH SCREENSHOT

[image]

OK in this pic the app is running in the foreground and Netbenas behind.

You can see the name I want changed is 'photosjFrame' - to something more meaningful for my app like "Photo Databse" etc etc

Hope this makes sense now…

Thanks

UPDATE 2

Here is another screenshot that I hope makes sense…

[image]

I have tried:

```
this.setTitle("Some meaningful title");
```

and

```
super("Some meaningful title");
```

but as you can see from the screen shot they change the title of the window open not of the application name (or whatever it is called)…

Thanks

Comment: share some screenshot.

Comment: maybe explaining *why* you want to do this will it clearer what you're trying to do?

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842648/netbeans-how-do-i-change-the-name-of-a-project

Comment: Thanks for the advice all… I want to change the name photosjFrame (the name of the class in Netbeans) that is next to the Apple icon (this is usually where the program name would be i.e. 'Netbeans', 'Safari', 'Photoshop' etc etc… I could change the class name but I though there may be another way to do it???

Answer (score 1):

Although your question is not as clear as it could be, and the screenshot still doesn't really show us what you desire, is it not as simple as calling...:

```
this.setTitle("Some meaningful title");
```

from within the jframe code, or...:

```
yourFrame.setTitle("Some meaningful title");
```

from wherever else is appropriate...

To change what text is shown in the Mac taskbar (top left), try adding the following lines:

```
System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar","true");
System.setProperty("com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name", "Some meaningful name"); 
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName())
```

Or, in newer versions of Java I beleive you can either:

1. Use the -XDock:name functionality
2. Set CFBundleName in the information property list. See this link:

See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/07-NativePlatformIntegration/NativePlatformIntegration.html

Comment: Thanks - I had already done that and it does not change the title I want to change. I will updated my original post with another screenshot that I hope will explain what I mean.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean, you want the name of the app that is displayed in the Mac taskbar to be something more meaningful.. I believe it can be be done by adding a few lines: `System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar","true");`
`System.setProperty("com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name", "Some meaningful name");`
`UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName())`
I don't have a Mac so i can't test it out but let me know how it goes..

Comment: Further to that, the Apple developer documentation suggests the following:
1. Use of the -XDock:name command
2. Or setting CFBundleName in the information property list.
See this link:
[Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/07-NativePlatformIntegration/NativePlatformIntegration.html)